# Using form with MUI onSubmit method not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI for components. After days of painful debugging, I found out that my form isn't calling the `onSubmit` method while the `Box` component is used to wrap the form. Please find below minimal ex. Why this is happening? `onClick` works fine though. Isn't `Box` component a valid use case here.  Should I be using API differently.

```
import { Box, Button, TextField } from '@mui/material';

export function MainForm() {

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log('submit called');
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        component="form"
      >
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <TextField />
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </Box>
    </div >
  )
}
```

Comment: I think that output of this is two wrapped `<form>` inside each other, and button triggering the upper one. Why are you exactly using `component='form'` there?

Comment: I just realized it works perfectly fine without `component=form`. I thought seeing the API I need to tell it what component I want to wrap, I felt a bit sceptical but thought maybe it's `mui` way.

Comment: Ok, here it is https://mui.com/components/box/ - `For non-MUI components, use the component prop.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you defined your Box component as a form, you have to place your `onSubmit` inside it.

```
<Box component="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <TextField />
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</Box>
```

You are overriding your MUI component, so the Box is already assuming itself as a form component.

Consider reading the [Overriding MUI components](https://mui.com/components/box/#overriding-mui-components) from the MUI documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Since the accepted answer doesn't really explain the reason why your code didn't work, here are some notes:

`Box component='form'` means that the `Box` is actually a form component with extra junk, your code would look like this as a result:

```
<form {...extraPropsFromBox}>
  <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <TextField />
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </form>
</form>
```

Nested form is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379622/9449426) in HTML 5 and using it is asking for trouble, in this case it probably ignores the `submit` handler in the nested form, the fix is remove the outer one. If you don't have a need to style the form container, just use a normal `form` tag. Use `Box` + `form` if you want to apply some styles quickly:

```
<Box component="form" onSubmit={submitHandler} sx={{ maxWidth: 300, bgcolor: 'gray' }}>
    <TextField />
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</Box>
```

> I thought seeing the API I need to tell it what component I want to wrap

All MUI components have a `component` prop that allows you to override the root component. Below is what the `Box` looks like under-the-hook. You do not have to specify the `component` because they all have a default value:

```
function Box({ component = 'div', ...boxProps }) {
  return <component {...boxProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I didn't specify the type of the submit button so adding the type solved the problem for me:

```html
<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```